# Difference between map[string]interface{} and interface{}

Tags: go, interface, go-map

I want to parse a JSON file to a `map[string]interface{}`:

```
var migrations map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(raw, &migrations)

fmt.Println(migrations["create_user"])
```

But I modified my code to point data to `interface{}`:

```
var migrations interface{}
json.Unmarshal(raw, &migrations)

// compile wrong here
fmt.Println(migrations["create_user"])
```

I don't understand much about difference between `map[string]interface{}` and `interface{}` in above case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because by default you need to type assert interface{} to get the underlying value of map[string]interface{}.

As per [GoLang](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) Specification

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression

```
x.(T)
```

> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

Also `Unmarshal` function requires pointer to `migration` of type interface{} or map[string]interface{}

```
var migrations interface{}
json.Unmarshal(raw, &migrations)

fmt.Println(migrations.(interface{}).(map[string]interface{})["create_user"])
```

Since `migrations` is not a map. So you cannot use its key to get the value. Interface{} don't have keys

Comment: Can I asked a question. If an object have similar field with one struct, can we cast that object to that struct. thanks.

Comment: yes we can Unmarshal the data into struct having tags for json. Checkout this [link](https://gobyexample.com/json)

Answer (score 46):

The difference between those two types is just what it seems:

1. `interface{}` is the "any" type, since *all* types implement the interface with no functions.
2. `map[string]interface{}` is a map whose keys are strings and values are any type.

When unmarshaling a byte array from JSON into memory it's easiest to use the `interface{}` type, since it can store any type of JSON document (objects, arrays, primitives, etc.); however, it may require more reflection to handle the underlying data.  Using a `map[string]interface{}` is common when you know the JSON document is an object and `[]interface{}` is common when you know the document is an array.

However, the best approach for unmarshaling JSON - especially when you know the structure of the documents ahead of time - is to define and use custom struct types that describe the data exactly. This way you can avoid any reflection and improve the legibility of your code.

Comment: thanks. The problem I meet is: I have an array of "object": each object is on different type,  so different struct, depend on field "type". So I must get each block separate before parsing.